# Convert Array to dataframe

Tags: arrays, r

I have the following array and I would like to convert it to a dataframe with the column names(Time and DepressionCount). I am pretty much a complete beginner to R and some help is greatly appreciated.

```
2004 2004.25 2004.5 2004.75 2005 2005.25 2005.5 2005.75
 875     820    785     857  844     841    726     766
```

Comment: 2004 2004.25  2004.5 2004.75    2005 2005.25  2005.5 2005.75....    
     875        820       785        857      844        841       726        766

Comment: If my edit is correct (is what you see with `print(depressionQuarterly)`), then accept it.

Comment: YES! it is indeed correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
dd=data.frame(t(array))
colnames(dd) = c("Time", "DepressionCount")
```

`t(array)` changes the two lines array into a two columns array, `data.frame` simply converts the array to a data.frame and `colnames` changes the column names of the data.frame.

Comment: Tried but got the following error: Error in depressionQuarterly[, c(1, 3)] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: What do `dim(array)` and `typeof(array)` give?

Comment: dimension is "40" and type is "integer"

Comment: This means your "array" is not an array in R, can you add to your post what you get with `print(array)`, to see what processing is recquired.

Comment: 2004 2004.25 2004.5 2004.75 2005 2005.25 2005.5 2005.75.... 875 820 785 857 844 841 726 766 –

Comment: The 875 is below 2004 the 820 below 2004.25 and so on. Sorry I am all new to this not sure how to format my answer better.

Comment: @DavidResch Does `names(array)` return NULL, or the values on top?

Comment: I have figured this out! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Used this: Depressiondframe <- melt(depressionQuarterly, id.vars="row.names")

Comment: Also work, you should put it in an answer and accept it so that people having the same problem can find the solution easily.